# use selenium cookies to download protected content with requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cookies, python-requests

the image come from my logged facebook account, for example

[this url](https://mbasic.facebook.com/photo/view_full_size/?fbid=287172731918173&ref_component=mbasic_photo_permalink&ref_page=%2Fwap%2Fphoto.php&refid=13&_ft_=qid.6613734168005236651%3Amf_story_key.930840450457689%3Atop_level_post_id.930840450457689%3Atl_objid.930840450457689%3Acontent_owner_id_new.100018763453401%3Acommerce_rank_obj.%7B%22viewer_id%22%3A100010997858874%2C%22target_id%22%3A1749033225224214%2C%22target_type%22%3A0%2C%22primary_position%22%3A0%2C%22secondary_position%22%3A0%2C%22search_query%22%3A%22%22%2C%22search_sid%22%3A%22%22%2C%22session_id%22%3A0%2C%22typeahead_sid%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ranking_signature%22%3A5430586371037982366%2C%22commerce_channel%22%3A103%2C%22commerce_type%22%3A2%2C%22ectr%22%3A0%2C%22value%22%3A0.4752378648108%2C%22model_scores%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22upsell_candidate_ids%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22upsell_type%22%3Anull%2C%22metadata%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22ad_imp_delivery_data_binary%22%3Anull%2C%22qp_renderer_type%22%3Anull%7D%3Asrc.22%3Aphoto_id.287172715251508&__tn__=%2Cg) need logged facebook session to access it, when i have logged account session, the url will be redirected to [this link](https://scontent.fcgk6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/l/t1.0-9/fr/cp0/e15/q65/44069119_287172735251506_8240333264946987008_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&_nc_ht=scontent.fcgk6-1.fna&oh=291c2d1695d59f87c52ec5bd91d09b78&oe=5C57F520) (that can be accessed from any where)

so my facebook account is logged from selenium, and i want use selenium cookies to download the image from requests

Answer (score 0):

There are a small example to show how to use the cookies from selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

dr = webdriver.Chrome()
...
dr.post(...)

with requests.Session() as se:
    req = se.get(url,cookies = {e.get("name"):e.get("value")  for e in dr.get_cookies()},headers = headers)
    with open("xxxx","wb") as f:
        f.write(req.content)
```